# jQuery not running under Citrix/ Enterprise

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have the following code:

```
$(".q68").click(function(){
        if($('#q68a2').is(':checked')) { 
            $('.q51').prop('disabled',false);
            $('.q52').prop('disabled',false);
            $('.q53').prop('disabled',false);
            $('.q54').prop('disabled',false);
        }
        if($('#q68a1').is(':checked')) { 
            $('.q51').prop('checked',false);
            $('.q52').prop('checked',false);
            $('.q53').prop('checked',false);
            $('.q54').prop('checked',false);
            $('.q51').prop('disabled',true);
            $('.q52').prop('disabled',true);
            $('.q53').prop('disabled',true);
            $('.q54').prop('disabled',true);
        }   
    });
```

As you can see, very simply, depending on what radio button `id` is selected, other radio buttons are disabled or enabled.  We've tested under IE7 and above in a XP, Vista, 7 and 8 environment but one of our clients has IE11 running within a Citrix environment and this code is not working.

I just wondered if anyone had an insight into why this might be - something obvious with the code I am missing?

Comment: @salniro - sadly, I can't get that information from the client at the moment, so I am running a little blind!  Hence the post on SO.  Just wondering if it was something obvious.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery from  a CDN? May be Citrix is set to load from the intranet only and not from the internet. Try using a local copy of jQuery if you're using a CDN.

Comment: @PeterKA - ah, thanks for that - will review where we are calling it from.